# How to check whether the inserted data into Google sheet is already present or not using Google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

While inserting a new row into the spreadsheet, I want to check whether that data is already present in the spreadsheet or not. And I also want to auto-increment a column for each row insertion into the sheet.

```
function insert_value(request, sheet) 
{

    var firstname = request.parameter.firstname;
    var lastname = request.parameter.lastname;
    var mobileno = request.parameter.mobileno;
    var emailid = request.parameter.emailid;
    var password = request.parameter.password;

    var flag = 1;
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
    for (var i = 1; i <= lr; i++) 
    {
        var mobileno1 = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
        var emailid1 = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
        if ((mobileno1 == mobileno)||(emailid1 == emailid))
        {
            flag = 0;
            var result = "User already exists..";
        }
    }
    //add new row with recieved parameter from client
    if (flag == 1) 
    {    
        var sno=sno+1;
        var lockerno=lockerno+1;
        var d = new Date();
        var currentTime = d.toLocaleString();
        var rowData = sheet.appendRow([sno,firstname,lastname,mobileno,emailid,password,lockerno]);
        var result = "Registered successful";
    }
```

Comment: Lots of existing questions on duplicate detection, yet you reference none of them. Why? You also just posted code and did not describe why that code is not suitable for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no. You have not even described what is wrong with your code, or how you have tried to change your code to meet your needs (and the resulting change to how your script operates). You need to describe your specific issue and the ways in which you have attempted to resolve it.

Comment: I also firmly believe that existing questions on duplicate detection are relevant to you. Of course, you must understand the question and the answer, and then use your own skill to adapt an answer to a similar case to your exact usage scenario.